Read and combine each row of multiple files and run a function on that combination (in chunks?) [R]
I have a somewhat complicated scenario of reading/combining in R and I am unsure how to attack the issue.
File Overview:
N files, each with the same Y columns and Z rows, but different data. Each file has differing numerical integers in the columns.
Combination Overview:
At each row, there will be a matrix output from the following zipper like combination: Each column is the row at each file, making N columns where each column matches one file. So, it is an YxN sized matrix and there are eventually Z of them.
At this stage, each matrix is used as part of the input for a function to be processed in order for each of the rows of the input files.
Now, there are ways to brute force this and just read everything in at once and process the data, but the data are just too large for this to be efficient. Is there a good way to efficiently read and combine files in this manner using chunks in R? Most important is keeping memory usage to a minimum.
Apologies for missing format ex... here N=4, Y=10 & Z=50
generate_matrix <- function() {
    matrix(sample(0:2, 50*10, replace = TRUE), nrow = 50, ncol = 10)
}
orig_matrices <- replicate(4, generate_matrix(), simplify = FALSE)
after_combination <- lapply(1:50, function(i) do.call(cbind, lapply(orig_matrices, function(x) x[i,])))

after_combination is then a list of 50 10x4 matrices

Can you please add an example in the form of e.g. set.seed(42); df_lst <- list(data.frame(matrix(sample(9), nrow=3)), data.frame(matrix(sample(9), nrow=3)), data.frame(matrix(sample(9), nrow=3))) plus expected output based on that df_lst.

Thanks - it's edited for you now. Apologies.

perhaps just use awk to transform the 4 files into 50 smaller files; then you could work on the small files independently.

Let's say you have a folder called orig_matrices containing only your N input files, say m1.csv, m2.csv, m3.csv ... mn.csv.
Then you can do the following
p=list(N=4, Y=10, Z=50)

for(i in 1:p$Z) {
  cmd = paste0("awk 'FNR==", i, "{print;nextfile}' m*.csv > ac", i,".csv")
  system(command = cmd)
  d = t(fread(paste0("ac", i, ".csv")))
  # < do something with d >
}

In this example, we iterate from 1 to p$Z, in this case, 50, each time creating the awk command that will pull the ith row from each of the csv files, running command then then reading in the csv. If you like, you could modify slightly to run in parallel: foreach(...) %dopar% {

Yeah I appreciate the idea - I think this is an unfortunately difficult strategy to use when each file will be containing hundreds of thousands of rows. The real need is a way to do this without preprocessing or reading everything into memory since only small chunks of data are needed at once.
